# Wordpress specific post when page loads

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am creating a Faculty Page in WordPress, and I am trying to figure out how to have a specific post load content when the 'Faculty Page' is clicked. After that the user has a choice to click on any faculty member which will change the content that was generated when the page was loaded.

The user will see the same content in the area when the page loads, then that content will change based on which faculty member they chose.

I know it isn't much to go on, but any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/query-or-show-a-specific-post-in-wordpress-php-code-example-44

Comment: This is a job spec you've posted. Break down the various problems into specific code related issues, have a go yourself, post what you've done and work through it.  You can post multiple questions on the same job until you've worked it through.

Comment: might be better on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/post-visibility/#sticky-posts

"By default, WordPress.com blogs display posts in reverse chronological order on the home page with the latest post at the top. There isn’t a way to display posts in chronological order, but you can mark some posts as Sticky to make them appear above the other posts. They will stay at the top of your posts until you uncheck that option on the Edit screen for that post.

You can mark a post as sticky by checking the option that says “Stick this post to the front page” in the Publish settings on any post."

edit:  Also, I think there is a WordPress exchange that might help you better than Stackoverflow.

edit:  Yeah, try here, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?as=1